# Postgres planner overcounts when joining 18 tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

Postgres Version: `PostgreSQL 9.6.4 on x86_64-alpine-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 6.3.0) 6.3.0, 64-bit`

We are having an issue with an `INNER JOIN` on 1 table with 18 others, and I would to get some pointers on where to look to fix it (we have had to hide our actual table names, but I have substituted this in the EXPLAIN as well).

#### Our schema:

- 1 Version Table (with bigserial `id`)
- 18 "Other" Tables (with bigint `versionId` references `version(id)`, and `anotherColumn` which is a `uuid`)
- "Other" tables have `unique(versionId, anotherColumn)`, so the left part of the multicolumn index is being used (see `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` below)

#### The test/query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)
SELECT Version.*,
 table6.versionid AS table6_versionId,
 <OTHER COLUMNS>

 table7.versionid AS table7_versionId,
  <OTHER COLUMNS>

 FROM asm.version Version 

 INNER JOIN table6 table6 ON table6.versionId = Version.id
 INNER JOIN table7 table7 ON table7.versionId = Version.id 
 <REPEATED FOR ALL 18 TABLES>

 WHERE Version.id = 30
```

#### The issue and potential solutions/questions:

- The query is slow (see `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) **despite using correct indexes**
- We sometimes run out of memory when retrieving query results. **This could be solved by increasing memory but I want to ensure there is nothing wrong with the query first**
- In the `EXPLAIN` below, we can see that the actual rows returned in some cases is overestimated (unless my math is terrible). When joining 4 tables with 2 rows each, we should have 8 rows returned, but the planner returns 16 (e.g. `(table10(2)+table5(2))+(table7(2)+table9(2)) = 16`. **Is this a pointer to some deeper issue?**

#### Explain Analyze:

```
'Nested Loop  (cost=75.20..250907.21 rows=18874368 width=2545) (actual time=1.337..2069.413 rows=262144 loops=1)'
'  Buffers: shared hit=38'
'  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=58.55..14939.23 rows=1179648 width=1841) (actual time=1.160..126.443 rows=16384 loops=1)'
'        Buffers: shared hit=30'
'        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.36..106.51 rows=1536 width=921) (actual time=0.347..2.167 rows=128 loops=1)'
'              Buffers: shared hit=16'
'              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=16.83..51.92 rows=48 width=585) (actual time=0.244..0.583 rows=16 loops=1)'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=10'
'                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.50..30.44 rows=8 width=281) (actual time=0.155..0.244 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=6'
'                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table5  (cost=4.18..12.64 rows=4 width=80) (actual time=0.046..0.058 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table5_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                          ->  Materialize  (cost=4.32..17.70 rows=2 width=201) (actual time=0.052..0.075 rows=2 loops=2)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.32..17.69 rows=2 width=201) (actual time=0.088..0.115 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                                      ->  Index Scan using version_pkey on version  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.038..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)'
'                                            Index Cond: (id = 30)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table10  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=160) (actual time=0.042..0.053 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table10_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                  Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                    ->  Materialize  (cost=8.34..20.90 rows=6 width=304) (actual time=0.023..0.056 rows=4 loops=4)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.34..20.87 rows=6 width=304) (actual time=0.071..0.145 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table7  (cost=4.17..11.28 rows=3 width=128) (actual time=0.031..0.042 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table7_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.17 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                                ->  Materialize  (cost=4.16..9.51 rows=2 width=176) (actual time=0.018..0.032 rows=2 loops=2)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table9  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=176) (actual time=0.023..0.035 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table9_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                  Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1'
'              ->  Materialize  (cost=12.53..35.46 rows=32 width=336) (actual time=0.008..0.048 rows=8 loops=16)'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=6'
'                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=12.53..35.30 rows=32 width=336) (actual time=0.090..0.261 rows=8 loops=1)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=6'
'                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.34..22.25 rows=8 width=256) (actual time=0.058..0.128 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table4  (cost=4.18..12.64 rows=4 width=80) (actual time=0.021..0.033 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table4_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                                ->  Materialize  (cost=4.16..9.51 rows=2 width=176) (actual time=0.015..0.029 rows=2 loops=2)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table6  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=176) (actual time=0.023..0.034 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table6_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                  Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                          ->  Materialize  (cost=4.18..12.66 rows=4 width=80) (actual time=0.008..0.018 rows=2 loops=4)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table11  (cost=4.18..12.64 rows=4 width=80) (actual time=0.019..0.029 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table11_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=1'
'        ->  Materialize  (cost=29.19..89.04 rows=768 width=920) (actual time=0.009..0.314 rows=128 loops=128)'
'              Buffers: shared hit=14'
'              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=29.19..85.20 rows=768 width=920) (actual time=0.793..2.118 rows=128 loops=1)'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=14'
'                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=12.53..35.30 rows=32 width=336) (actual time=0.603..0.742 rows=8 loops=1)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=6'
'                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.34..22.25 rows=8 width=256) (actual time=0.554..0.607 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table1  (cost=4.18..12.64 rows=4 width=80) (actual time=0.503..0.510 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.483..0.483 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                                ->  Materialize  (cost=4.16..9.51 rows=2 width=176) (actual time=0.022..0.032 rows=2 loops=2)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table12  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=176) (actual time=0.030..0.036 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table12_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                  Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                          ->  Materialize  (cost=4.18..12.66 rows=4 width=80) (actual time=0.012..0.019 rows=2 loops=4)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table2  (cost=4.18..12.64 rows=4 width=80) (actual time=0.034..0.041 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table2_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                    ->  Materialize  (cost=16.66..40.36 rows=24 width=584) (actual time=0.025..0.096 rows=16 loops=8)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=8'
'                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=16.66..40.24 rows=24 width=584) (actual time=0.175..0.415 rows=16 loops=1)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=8'
'                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.34..20.87 rows=6 width=240) (actual time=0.069..0.116 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table3  (cost=4.17..11.28 rows=3 width=96) (actual time=0.027..0.033 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table3_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.17 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                  Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                                      ->  Materialize  (cost=4.16..9.51 rows=2 width=144) (actual time=0.019..0.027 rows=2 loops=2)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table14  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=144) (actual time=0.027..0.031 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                  Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table14_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                        Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                                ->  Materialize  (cost=8.33..19.08 rows=4 width=344) (actual time=0.026..0.049 rows=4 loops=4)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.33..19.06 rows=4 width=344) (actual time=0.091..0.140 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table13  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=160) (actual time=0.051..0.055 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                  Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table13_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                        Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                        Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                                            ->  Materialize  (cost=4.16..9.51 rows=2 width=184) (actual time=0.018..0.026 rows=2 loops=2)'
'                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                                  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table8  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=184) (actual time=0.026..0.030 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                        Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                        Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                                        Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table8_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                                              Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                                              Buffers: shared hit=1'
'  ->  Materialize  (cost=16.65..38.42 rows=16 width=704) (actual time=0.002..0.037 rows=16 loops=16384)'
'        Buffers: shared hit=8'
'        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=16.65..38.34 rows=16 width=704) (actual time=0.161..0.389 rows=16 loops=1)'
'              Buffers: shared hit=8'
'              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.33..19.06 rows=4 width=288) (actual time=0.078..0.128 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table15  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=144) (actual time=0.022..0.027 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                          Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                          Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table15_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                    ->  Materialize  (cost=4.16..9.51 rows=2 width=144) (actual time=0.026..0.036 rows=2 loops=2)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table16  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=144) (actual time=0.043..0.048 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table16_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=1'
'              ->  Materialize  (cost=8.33..19.08 rows=4 width=416) (actual time=0.021..0.043 rows=4 loops=4)'
'                    Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.33..19.06 rows=4 width=416) (actual time=0.068..0.116 rows=4 loops=1)'
'                          Buffers: shared hit=4'
'                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table17  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=176) (actual time=0.027..0.031 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table17_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=1'
'                          ->  Materialize  (cost=4.16..9.51 rows=2 width=240) (actual time=0.018..0.027 rows=2 loops=2)'
'                                Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on table18  (cost=4.16..9.50 rows=2 width=240) (actual time=0.027..0.032 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                      Recheck Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                      Heap Blocks: exact=1'
'                                      Buffers: shared hit=2'
'                                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table18_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.16 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=2 loops=1)'
'                                            Index Cond: (versionid = 30)'
'                                            Buffers: shared hit=1'
'Planning time: 6.766 ms'
'Execution time: 2653.397 ms'
```

Comment: The range table for your query is exceeding the `geqo_threshold` (typically 12) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-GEQO-THRESHOLD You could try lowering the `join_collapse_limit` and/or move tightly correlated parts of the query into CTEs or subqueries.

Comment: Why do you need 18 nearly identical tables, each of them containing one or two relevant rows? (IOW: this could be a data modelling issue)

Comment: Is `id` the primary key of `Version`? Is it (part of) the PK of the other tables. (your estimated number of rows are either spot-on, or a multiple of the actual number of rows. And it looks very Carthesian to me ...)

Comment: `id` is the primary key of Version, and `version.id` is part of the foreign key of all the other tables (The other tables have `PRIMARY KEY(versionId, uuidColumn)`. Can you please explain a little more how I might have ended up with a multiple of the actual number of rows in the actual row count of `EXPLAIN`?